# Fetching MySQL session variable value from spring boot application

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, session-variables

I had created and fetched a session variable in my mysql DB with below commands:

```
>SET @FLAG = true;
>select @FLAG;
```

I am trying to fetch the same variable from my spring boot application using a Named query like below:

```
@NamedQuery(name = "Flag.get", query = "select @FLAG;")
Error:
Flag.get failed because of: org.hibernate.QueryException: unexpected char: '@' [select @FLAG;]
```

Can someone please let me know how to read values of DB session variables from spring boot application

Answer (score 1):

You can not use namedquery with non-JPA query language as described in the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.named-queries)

> The examples use the  element and @NamedQuery annotation. The queries for these configuration elements have to be defined in the JPA query language. Of course, you can use  or @NamedNativeQuery too. These elements let you define the query in native SQL by losing the database platform independence.

So you can use **NamedNativeQueries**, below is example how to define them in a entity class

```
@SqlResultSetMapping(name="flagResult", columns = { @ColumnResult(name = "@FLAG")})

@NamedNativeQueries(
  {
    @NamedNativeQuery(
      name = "native1",
      query = "select * from user where name=:name",
      resultClass = User.class
    ),
    @NamedNativeQuery(
      name = "nativeSessionSet",
      query = "set @FLAG=:name",
      resultClass = User.class
    ),
    @NamedNativeQuery(
      name = "nativeSessionGet",
      query = "select @FLAG",
      resultSetMapping = "flagResult"
    ),
    @NamedNativeQuery(
      name = "UpdateStoredProc",
      query = "call UPDATE_USER(:id, :name, :mail)",
      resultClass = User.class
    ),
  }
)
@Data
@Entity // This tells Hibernate to make a table out of this class
public class User {
```

in order to call that native query from a repository check code below

```
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Integer> {
    public User findByName(String name);
    @Query(name = "native1")
    public User native1(String name);
    @Modifying
    @Query(name = "nativeSessionSet")
    @Transactional
    public void nativeSessionSet(String name);
    @Query(name = "nativeSessionGet")
    public Object nativeSessionGet();
```

here are the outputs in my machine
[image: calling example spring boot app with curl]

you can find running example [here](https://github.com/ozkanpakdil/spring-examples/tree/master/mysql-session)